# How to pattern-match a hash where a value is in a known array?

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

I am trying to pattern-match a hash.  I want to know whether the hash has a key whose string value is in an array of known strings (along with some other criteria which I have working).

Here is what I have so far:

```
THINGS = %w[red orange yellow]

hash = {foo: 'yellow'}

case hash
in {foo: THINGS}
  # I want this to match but it doesn't
else
  # ..
end
```

Is this possible with pattern matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of pattern matching and [@Rajagopalan suggestion of `any?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77178826/1978251) by using a guard clause.

```
THINGS = %w[red orange yellow]

def foo_color_match(hash)
  case hash
  in foo: a if THINGS.any?(a)
   "matched #{a}"
  else
   'no_match'
  end
end

h = {foo: 'yellow'}
h1 = {foo: 'black'}

p foo_color_match(h)
#=> "matched yellow"
p foo_color_match(h1)
#=> "no match"
```

Otherwise we can pull some weird tricks like

```
THINGS = %w[red orange yellow]

def foo_color_match(hash, color_palette: THINGS)
  m = color_palette.to_enum 
  def m.===(other) = member?(other)

  case hash
  in foo: ^m => a
   "matched #{a}"
  else
   'no_match'
  end
end

h = {foo: 'yellow'}
h1 = {foo: 'black'}

p foo_color_match(h)
#=> "matched yellow"
p foo_color_match(h1)
#=> "no match"
```

Comment: Thanks for both these solutions.  The second is an interesting trick – I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this way. Use `any?` method.

```
THINGS = %w[red orange yellow]

hash = {foo: 'yellow'}

if THINGS.any? { |color| hash[:foo] == color }
  # This will match if the value of :foo is included in THINGS
else
  # ..
end
```

Comment: That's the kind of thing I wrote first.  I would like to know if I can replace it with pattern matching instead.

Comment: Definitely , please go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

```rb
THINGS = %w[red orange yellow]
hash = {foo: "yellow"}

case hash
in {foo: color} if THINGS in [*,^color,*]
  "Matched: #{color}"
else
  "No match"
end
#=> "Matched: yellow"
```

If only some kind of a pipe splat `*|THINGS` existed:

```rb
hash = {foo: "red"}

case hash
in {foo: "yellow"|"red"|"orange" => color}
  "Matched: #{color}"
else
  "No match"
end
#=> "Matched: red"
```

Comment: Thanks for these.  The first one is interesting because in the guard clause you're seeing if the known array matches the just-matched value, instead of trying to see if the value matches the known array.  I wouldn't have thought of reversing it like that.

Comment: Your second idea is very close to what I was hoping might be possible.  If only your pipe splat were real!  I came close with `RE = Regexp.new(THINGS.map { |thing| Regexp.escape(thing) }.join('|'))` and then, above the case statement, `re = RE`, and then `in foo: ^re => color`.

Comment: @AndyStewart for regexp just: `Regexp.union(THINGS)`

Comment: Thank you, that's much better!  Somehow I forgot about `Regexp.union()`.